# Using rigid for reluctant attitude

Tags: word-usage

My friend wrote the following sentence to show her reluctance towards watching movies:

> I am quite rigid towards watching movies in cinema halls.

I didn't find any definition in Oxford dictionary for **"rigid"** which means **"a reluctant attitude"**.

Here, she meant that she always try to avoid going cinema halls for watching movies. Her full statement was as follows:

> I am quite rigid towards watching movies in cinema halls. However, when my family pushed I got ready and joined them there.

Did she write a correct statement? I have found many other people using a similar statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Rigid* means hard, stiff - the opposite of *flexible*.

It typically describes/implies a physical object.  To overcome this assumption you need a lot of literary or poetic-license type of context.  More than what you provide in your example.

The adverb form *rigidly* is somewhat more open to describe non-physical things:

> I am rigidly insistent upon watching movies in cinema halls.

A better word for your situation would be *particular about*, which is used to talk about preferences or wants.

> I am particular about watching movies in cinema halls