# The usage of rigid, Is it to emphasize something?

Tags: word-usage

I found this sentence from a book (English book):

> Let's sit somewhere else; they always talk shop over lunch, and it
> bores me **rigid**.

The definition of this word is stiff or inflexible according to some dictionaries. I think that word has the alternative meaning in the sentence above. There's also a discussion [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/141102/110852) discussing the usage of rigid, but I still haven't got any clue. As far as I can understand, I guess it's to emphasize something when we use *really*, right.

For instance, the last clause (in my opinion) can be replaced by:

> ... it really bores me.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: In the U.S., the more common variant of the expression is to be "bored stiff."  It means to be extremely bored.  No idea why.  m-w.com suggests that the word "stiff" can mean "extremely," and cites "bored stiff" as an example, but I've never heard the word "stiff" used this way except in combination with "bored."  I've never heard this expression with "rigid," but apparently it exists.

Comment: @cruthers There's also "*scared stiff*"

Comment: @gotube: That one makes some degree of figurative sense considering the physical meaning of "stiff" - i.e., so scared that you can't even move - so it's not clear to me that "stiff" means "extremely" in the more general sense in that expression.  I had always assumed there was some historical figurative explanation of "bored stiff" too, but the idea that you're so bored that you can't even move seems like a stretch.

Comment: The idea of being figuratively immobilised by extreme emotion or powerful experience is fairly common - I remember reading an account of a young upper class British teenage girl in the 1930s, a virgin, discussing sex with a slightly older girl. 'What was it like?' asked the younger girl. 'Riveting' was the reply.

Comment: _Bored stiff_ is the usual idiom in British English too. I think _bored rigid_ is just a humorous variation.

Comment: @cruthers - one can be [bored, scared, or worried](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bored-scared-worried-stiff) stiff. It is common for such expressions to be inventively modified by native speakers, e.g. as in this case by replacing 'stiff' by 'rigid'. Also 'witless' or (vulgarly) 'shitless' are possible.

Comment: "To be honest, I was scared rigid" - mountaineer about his feelings prior to attempting Mont Blanc.

Comment: "As we all know, there are many others ways of expressing ennui: “bored to pieces,” “bored to death,” “bored to tears,” “bored to distraction,” “bored stiff,” “bored rigid,” “bored silly,” and so on." - Grammarphobia article explaining [bored to flinders](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/01/flinders.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use figurative language to express that an idea, experience, emotion, etc, has affected us very strongly. Often the figurative expression will pretend that the experience:

- made us weep - bored to tears
- killed us  - bored to death
- paralysed us - bored/scared/worried stiff or rigid
- caused us to become mentally paralysed or incapable - bored/scared/worried witless (or stupid)
- rendered us unconscious - bored senseless
- (vulgarly) extremely constipated - bored/scared/worried shitless

The supposed physical or mental effect may have some basis in reality or may be imaginary.

The more strongly counter-factual the expression, the stronger the feeling, e.g. My son made me watch a 'superhero' film, and I literally died of boredom waiting for it to end.

When I was very small my aunt promised to take me to the seaside in her car, and my mother told someone I was 'thrilled to bits'. Of course I did not break into little pieces, although I remember the mental image that the expression produced (a Michael made of glass, shattered).